# how to analyze geographical data

Tags: python, gis, geo, geotiff

I plan to analyze geographical data, but I've never done this before.
Basically, what I'm trying to do is the following: I was hoping I could get satellite images/data for the US and analyze it. Specifically, I want to add a US county grid over an image of the USA and then calculate the amount of the color green per US county (as a measure for vegetation/forests).
Could you give me some example codes or resources specifically on how  I would calculate the "greenness" with a geotiff files? and how  to  do this for  a specific US county (grid cell)?